# bulk insert elasticSearch for autocomplete suggestion

Tags: elasticsearch, bulk, completion

How to bulk insert into suggestions

here is mapping

```
PUT /myindex/autocomplete/_mapping
{
   "autocomplete": {
      "properties": {
         "name": {
            "type": "string"
         },
         "suggest": {
            "type": "completion",
            "index_analyzer": "simple",
            "search_analyzer": "simple",
            "payloads": true
         }
      }
   }
}
```

here is few data that works if I inert then one by one

```
POST /myindex/autocomplete/
{
   "name": "Nevermind",
   "suggest": {
      "input": [
         "Nevermind",
         "Nirvana"
      ],
      "output": "Nirvana - Nevermind",
      "payload": {
         "tip": 1,
         "oid": 1
      },
      "weight": 34
   }
}
```

how to do a BULK insert of suggestions?

```
PUT /myindex/autocomplete/_bulk
{
   "name": "Nevermind",
   "suggest": {
      "input": [
         "Nevermind"
      ],
      "output": "Nirvana - Nevermind",
      "payload": {
         "tip": 1,
         "oid": 1
      },
      "weight": 34
   }
}
{
   "name": "Bleach",
   "suggest": {
      "input": [
         "Bleach"
      ],
      "output": "Nirvana - Bleach",
      "payload": {
         "tip": 2,
         "oid": 3
      },
      "weight": 20
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to format your data according to what the [bulk operation expects](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html), i.e. one line for the "index" action and another line with the JSON source all separated by new line characters (including on the last line):

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/myindex/autocomplete/_bulk -d '
{ "index":{"_id": 1} }
{ "name": "Nevermind",  "suggest": { "input": [ "Nevermind" ], "output": "Nirvana - Nevermind", "payload": {  "tip": 1, "oid": 1 }, "weight": 34 } }
{ "index":{"_id": 2} }
{ "name": "Bleach",  "suggest": { "input": [ "Bleach" ], "output": "Nirvana - Bleach", "payload": {  "tip": 2, "oid": 3 }, "weight": 20 } }
'
```

Comment: "input" and "output" is the key :)